# How Can I Login In Laravel With Predefined Email/Username and Password?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authentication

I want to login with predefined email address and password in laravel.It will be done in manually. what will be the process? I have set login page. and now i want to login my dashboard without registering and with predefined email and password.

```
<form class="login-form" action="dashboard.html">        
 <div class="login-wrap">
  <p class="login-img"><i class="icon_lock_alt"></i></p>

 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_profile"></i></span>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autofocus>
                    </div>
 <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon_key_alt"></i></span>           
 <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>

 </div>
  </form>
```

How can i do that,what will the process thanks for help.

Comment: What is the meaning of "predefined" ? Add one row to user table in database first ?

Comment: from user table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creade a seeder class; `php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder` the file will be generated at seeders folder open it and create a default user like so:

```
User::create(['name'=>'test',
'email'=>'email',
'password'=>bcrypt('password')]);
```

at the top. `use User`
or do:

```
{
    DB::table('users')->insert([
        'name' => 'User1',
        'email' => 'user1@email.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
    ]);
```

after this; add  to execute with `$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);`
in `DatabaseSeeder.php` or install in seeds folderfile and  call the custom seeder

then each time you want to have a default user after migration run `php artisan db: seed`

Answer (score 0):

I think creating new **Artisan Console command** is a good choice rather than `db:seed` . Through this way, you can define your own username, email, password **DYNAMICALLY** like you asked, instead of just hardcoding. Tested in Laravel 5.4

1) Create a Artisan Console command using below, which will create a `AddLogin.php` inside `app/Console/Commands` 
    php artisan make:command AddLogin
2) Replace the `AddLogin` content with the following

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\User;    //User Model

class AddLogin extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'add:login';    //our new artisan console command

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Create New Login Credentials';


    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $name = $this->ask('Enter Name :');
        $email = $this->ask('Enter Email :');
        $password = $this->secret('Enter Password :');
        //Password won't be visible when you type

        User::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => bcrypt($password)
        ]);

        $this->info('New Login Credentials created successfully!');
    }
}
```

3) Register the command in `app/Console/Kernel.php` file by adding

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    Commands\AddLogin::class
];
```

4) Whenever you want to create a new Login Credentials, just type

```
php artisan add:login
```

in cmd and provide promted details.

DONE. Hope this is useful to someone.

[image]